# Bootstrap: Gutter space issue

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, css

I am using Bootstrap sb admin template. I tried to add 3 cols in a row but problem is that there is no space around these boxes and they are merged together. I tried  to change bootsrap file by cdn link , removed all the css files one by one but that did not work. This is my html structure  (Codeigniter view)

```
 <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-12">
            <h1 class="page-header"> Services </h1>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-12 service-block">
            <img src="<?php echo base_url()?>assets/images/service-1.png" class="img-responsive  center-block">
            <h3 class="text-center">Body Works</h>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-12 service-block">
            <img src="<?php echo base_url()?>assets/images/service-1.png" class="img-responsive  center-block">
            <h3 class="text-center">Body Works</h>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-12 service-block">
            <img src="<?php echo base_url()?>assets/images/service-1.png" class="img-responsive  center-block">
            <h3 class="text-center">Body Works</h>
        </div>

    </div>
    <!-- /.row -->
</div>
```

This is the only css for these services blocks

```
.service-block{
        background: #EDEDED;
        height: 220px;
     }
    .service-block img{
        margin-top: 15%;
        margin-bottom: 9px;
    }
```

This is the output i get

[image]

can someone help me what could be the issue  with this

Answer (score -1):

You have 3 columns in one row, but each column reserves 3 spaces in the grid, which would be 9. But bootstrap requires you to fill 12 spaces in the grid. So use:
`<div class="col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-12 service-block">`

Comment: please re go through my question

Comment: Instead of down-voting, have your code uploaded on jsfiddle or somewhere to let us see what kind of issue you have and what you are expecting.